# Calculate priority based on DateTime with left shift

Tags: c#, java, .net, algorithm

I have a Response object and each `Response` object is having `DateTime` property on which we store the datetime of its createion. I store the Response object as a Queue inside a `Dictionary` which key is `Priority`(long) and value is `Queue` of Responses.

I am doing left bit shift to calculate priority. `this` refers to `Response` object.

```
this.Priority = ((((long)this.Id) << 0x010) & 0FF0000) | (UInt32)(((this.TypeId << 0x08) & 0FF00));
```

this.Priority will be the key for dictionary.

I am going to Add `DateTime` property in this priority calculation. For me, the oldest `DateTime` should get highest priority in the dictionary. So the calculation should yield bigger number for the oldest `DateTime` than the newest `DateTime`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really wrap my head around this yet but...

I would take the difference between DateTime.MaxValue and DateTime.Now, then get the Ticks and use that to shift with the priority.

```
TimeSpan timeToMajorFailure = DateTime.MaxValue - DateTime.Now; // The world will end
long ticks = timeToMajorFailure.Ticks;                          // on December 31, 9999
```

This way the ticks value will be lower for newer tasks. Note that my substraction does not take in account different time zones. If you need that you can use the DateTimeOffset class.

Interesting question and I hope my suggestion helps.